# i wrote this java programe for tictactoe game but it dosent seem working

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe

i made two classes in game package
first class gui is for gui and other class main for main coding ,the problem i am getting is when ever i click on any button button set text to "x" , i am not able to switch to other player please help me i am really very confused ,thanx ya all.

```
package game;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class gui implements ActionListener
{
main main=new main();

JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;
JLabel l;
public gui()
{

JFrame f=new JFrame("TicTacToe");
JPanel p=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel p1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
JPanel p2=new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
f.setSize(400,600);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.add(p);
f.add(p1);
f.add(p2);
p2.add(p);
p2.add(p1);
l=new JLabel();
b1=new JButton();
b2=new JButton();
b3=new JButton();
b4=new JButton();
b5=new JButton();
b6=new JButton();
b7=new JButton();
b8=new JButton();
b9=new JButton();
p.add(l);
p1.add(b1);
p1.add(b2);
p1.add(b3);
p1.add(b4);
p1.add(b5);
p1.add(b6);
p1.add(b7);
p1.add(b8);
p1.add(b9);
b1.addActionListener(this);
b2.addActionListener(this);
b3.addActionListener(this);
b4.addActionListener(this);
b5.addActionListener(this);
b6.addActionListener(this);
b7.addActionListener(this);
b8.addActionListener(this);
b9.addActionListener(this);


}
public static void main (String args[])
{
gui i=new gui();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

if(ae.getSource()==b1)
{

    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b1.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b1.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b2)
{
    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b2.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b2.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b3)
{

    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b3.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b3.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b4)
{
    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b4.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b4.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b5)
{

    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b5.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b5.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b6)
{
    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b6.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b6.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b7)
{

    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b7.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b7.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b8)
{
    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b8.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b8.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
if(ae.getSource()==b9)
{
    main.chkTurn();
    if(main.playerTurn=true)
    {

        b9.setText("X");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=false;
    }
    if(main.playerTurn=false)
    {

        b9.setText("O");
        main.checkWin();
        main.playerTurn=true;
    }

}
}
}
```

and other class is

```
package game;

public class main {
public static boolean playerTurn=true;
public static int event=0;
public static boolean playerWon=false;
public static boolean comWon=false;
public static gui board=new gui(); 
public static void main(String args[])
{
//main main=new main();

}
public static void chkTurn()
{
if(event==(1|3|5|7|9))
{
    playerTurn=true;
}
else if(event==(2|4|6|8|10))
{
    playerTurn=false;
}
}

public static void checkWin()
{
if(board.b1.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b4.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b7.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b1.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b9.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b1.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b2.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b3.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b3.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b7.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b3.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b9.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b7.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b8.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b9.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b4.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b6.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b2.getText().equals("X"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("X"))
{
    if(board.b8.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        playerWon=true;
        comWon=false;
        board.l.setText("Player 1 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b1.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b4.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b7.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b1.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b9.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b1.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b2.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b3.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b3.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b7.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b3.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b9.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b7.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b8.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b9.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b4.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b6.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}
if(board.b2.getText().equals("O"))
{
if(board.b5.getText().equals("O"))
{
    if(board.b8.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        playerWon=false;
        comWon=true;
        board.l.setText("Player 2 Won!");
    }
}
}

}
}
```

Comment: event==(1|3|5|7|9) have you intentionally compressed the if statements or there is some new magic i didn't know about?

Comment: Not working means what? Does it throw any exception or does not work as expected?

Comment: Also, would greatly help if we knew what was not working...are you getting an error compiling, an exception, or some logic doesn't seem to function.  What have you tried thus far?  This is not a game of 20 questions, and you will get more help if you can provide as many details up-front as possible.

Comment: it gets compiled successfully but clicking on every button gives X,

Answer (score 1):

The code is syntactically correct, but it probably does not what you expect.

For instance the condition `event==(1|3|5|7|9)` will **not** evaluate whether `event` is an odd number or has the value 1 or 3 or 5 or... rather it will always be false if event is an integer.

Try `event%2!=0` for oddness.

Also look at the other answers giving you clues of what might be wrong in your code.

You should thoroughly review your java grammar skills. Or maybe you should take these optimizations into a completely new language :-)

Just out of curiosity: what language are you coming from if Java is not your first language?

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
if(main.playerTurn=false)
```

checks if "main.playerTurn=false" is true. It is important to note that

```
main.playerTurn=false   is equivalent to    false  (the RHS value)
main.playerTurn=true    is equivalent to    true
```

Thus you see the undesired behaviour, the correct way to do this is

```
if(main.playerTurn==false)
```

or

```
if(!main.playerTurn)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(main.playerTurn=false)` will be always `false`.

Should be:

```
if(!main.playerTurn)
```

That's why we don't use `==` when we compare `boolean`s. This might lead to problems like this one.

In your case, you're *assigning* `false` to `main.platerTurn`, and since the expression of the assignment returns the **assigned** value this condition will never be satisfied.

The same for `if(main.playerTurn=true)`.

Also, what is `if(event==(1|3|5|7|9))`? :( Change it to:

`if(event==1||event==3||event==5||event==7||event==9)`